# Order type of N and Q

Tags: integers, natural-numbers, well-orders

Studying linear orderings, I learned two theorems.

1. Suppose two linearly ordered sets A and B satisfy the following:
   (1) countably infinite,
   (2) dense, i.e. if x<z then there exists y such that x<y<z,
   (3) no first and last elements.
   Then, A and B are order isomorphic.
2. Suppose two linearly ordered sets A and B satisfy the following:
   (1) least upper bound property,
   (2) separable, i.e. there exists countable dense subset,
   (3) no first and last elements.
   Then, A and B are order isomorphic.

I thought the conditions of first theorem determine the order type of Q, and the conditions of second theorem determine the order type of R.

What I wonder is the conditions which determine the order type of N and Z.

I guess the conditions that determine the order type of N are the following:
(1) countably infinite,
(2) well ordered,
(3) For all elements, except the first element, there exists immediate predecessor.

And, I guess the conditions that determine the order type of Z are the following:
(1) countably infinite,
(2) For all elements, there exist immediate predecessor and successor,
(3) least upper bound property.

I wonder whether these conditions really determine the order type of N, Z respectively, or whether there are better conditions.

Comment: These sound right to me! Your characterisation of $\Bbb N$ is closely related to the fact that "$\omega$ is the smallest nonzero limit ordinal". That roughly says "$\Bbb N$ is non-empty, well-ordered, has no largest element, and only the first element has no predecessor". Are you looking for proofs that your characterisations are correct?

Comment: Those conditions are just my guesses. So I'm curious if those conditions are really right, and if they are, how to prove them.

Comment: For $\Bbb N$, you can drop "countably" from (1). For $\Bbb Z$, you can drop all of (1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Z$, they are quickly seen to meet the indicated conditions. Conversely:

Suppose $A$ is a infinite well-ordered set where every element $x$ except the least has an immediate predecessor, denoted by $p(x)$.
Define $f: \Bbb N \to A$ inductively by

- $f(0) = \min A$ (or $f(1)$, depending on your favorite definition of $\Bbb N$).
- for all $n > 0, f(n) = \min\{m \in A: m > f(n-1)\}$.

This defines $f$ as an order-preserving injection. Suppose $f$ is not surjective. Let $x = \min A \setminus f(\Bbb N)$. $x \ne \min A$, since $f(0) = \min A$, so $x$ has a predecessor. But $p(x) \notin A \setminus f(\Bbb N)$ since it is smaller than $x$. Thus $p(x) = f(n)$ for some $n$. But then $f(n+1) = \min\{m \in A: m > p(x)\}$. So $f(n+1) > p(x)$, but because $x > p(x), f(n+1) \le x$. If $f(n+1) < x$, then $p(x) < f(n+1) < x$ contradicts that $p(x)$ is the immediate predecessor of $x$, while $f(n+1) = x$ contradicts that $x \in A\setminus f(\Bbb N)$. This cannot be. Thus $f$ must be an order-preserving bijection between $\Bbb N$ and $A$. They have the same order-type.

Now suppose $B$ is a non-empty linearly ordered set for which every $x \in B$ has an immediate predecessor $p(x)$ and immediate successor $s(x)$, and such every non-empty $C \subset B$ which is bounded above has a least upper bound. Note that because of the predecessor condition, this least upper bound $m$ will always be the maximum element of $C$. If $m$ were not an element of $C$, then $p(m)$ would also be an upper bound for $C$. Thus we could have equivalently given the condition that every non-empty subset of $B$ that is bounded above must have a maximum. Another equivalent is that every non-empty subset of $C$ that is bounded below has a minimum, as the set of lower bounds is bounded above, and thus has a maximum, whose successor must be the minimum of $C$.

Define $f: \Bbb Z \to B$ by choosing an arbitrary element of $B$ for $f(0)$, then defining inductively for $n > 0$

- $f(n) = s(f(n-1)) = \min\{x \in B : x > f(n-1)\}$
- $f(-n) = p(f(-n+1)) = \max\{x \in B : x < f(-n+1)\}$

This defines $f$ as an order-preserving injection of $\Bbb Z$ into $B$.

Suppose $x \in B \setminus f(\Bbb Z)$. If $x < f(0)$, let $z = \min\{y \in f(\Bbb Z) : x < y\}$. This set is non-empty and bounded below, so $z$ must exist. Since $z \in f(\Bbb Z)$, there is some $m \in\Bbb Z$ with $z = f(m)$. But $f(m-1) < f(m)$ so it must be that $f(m-1) < x$, but $f(m-1) = p(f(m)) = p(z)$, so $p(z) < x < z$, which cannot be. A similar contradiction occurs if $x > f(0)$. So there cannot be such an $x \in B \setminus f(\Bbb Z)$. I.e., $f$ is bijective, and $\Bbb Z$ and $B$ must have the same order-type.

The condition on $B$ could be simplified to $B$ is not empty, has no maximum or minimum, and for every non-empty $C \subseteq B$, if $C$ is bounded below, then $C$ has a minimum, and if $C$ is bounded above, then $C$ has a maximum.

Comment: Thank you!! You solved my curiosity.